# Symfony2 Role Confusion; how to NOT store them in the database?

Tags: symfony

I'm working on a Symfony app that will have some basic roles that can be assigned to users. *Note, I'm not using the [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) because I don't need more than half the features in it.*

I have my users defined in the database, but I'd like to keep the role definitions out of the database. But several examples and other tutorials I've found keep the roles in the database, and use a `ManyToMany` relationship to assign them to users. This seems odd to me, since the actual *use of the roles is hardcoded into the app*.

For example, if I have a custom role `ROLE_EDITOR`, I have several routes and controllers that I may restrict to `ROLE_EDITOR`. Why would I "define" this role in the database? That means when developing my application and I add a new user role, I have to either write a script to programmatically insert a new role into the DB or do it manually, before the code is deployed that makes use of the role. I don't want admins to be able to add/edit/delete roles. It should be a design decision done programmatically.

In Drupal, there's a concept of Roles and Permissions. You define permissions in code and check against those, and then roles are defined in the database and are assigned permissions. But it seems that Symfony just has the concept of Roles.

I'm hoping someone can fill in a missing piece of information for me or something. How can I implement a system where the role assignments are done in the database, but the roles themselves are managed via code only?

My instinct is to just create a single entity that relates to `User` and has a string field for the `ROLE_NAME`. But this seems to go against the paradigm of having a real `Role` entity.

Comment: you have only one class for the user or you have many classes depending on the role ?

Comment: You can define your roles in security configuration - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles

Comment: you could store the roles as serialized/json array in a *roles* field for each user

Comment: FOSUserBundle solves that using Groups. Then groups are to roles in SF2 what roles are to permissions in Drupal. Maybe you can borrow the concept https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/Group.php

Comment: All you have to make sure of is that $user->getRoles() returns the groups' roles as well.

Comment: +1 for the confusion. I always though that "roles" should be called "permissions" in symfony. This is very confusing.